# Why does package yahoo_earnings_calendar stop working?

Tags: python, yahoo-api, yfinance

I am using package yahoo_earnings_calendar to get earnings calendar from Yahoo and it worked fine one month ago.

```
from yahoo_earnings_calendar import YahooEarningsCalendar
yec = YahooEarningsCalendar()
yec.get_earnings_of('box')
```

But today I find it will raise an error. I printed the error and it send me this html message.

```
    Yahoohtml{height:100%}body{background:#fafafc url(https://s.yimg.com/nn/img/sad-panda-201402200631.png) 50% 50%;background-size:cover;height:100%;text-align:center;font:300 18px "helvetica neue",helvetica,verdana,tahoma,arial,sans-serif}table{height:100%;width:100%;table-layout:fixed;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;border:0}h1{font-size:42px;font-weight:400;color:#400090}p{color:#1a1a1a}#message-1{font-weight:bold;margin:0}#message-2{display:inline-block;*display:inline;zoom:1;max-width:17em;_width:17em}document.write('&test="+encodeURIComponent("%")+'" width="0px" height="0px"/>');var beacon=new Image();beacon.src="//bcn.fp.yahoo.com/p?s=1197757129&t="+new Date().getTime()+"&src=aws&err_url="+encodeURIComponent(document.URL)+"&err=%&test="+encodeURIComponent("%");Will be right back...Thank you for your patience.Our engineers are working quickly to resolve the issue.
```

I find other similar question. It seems that Yahoo do not want us scrape their data. But those posts do not solve my code block. Can somebody help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  Here's the link to my question that was answered today.  Yahoo redid their site, so now you have to upgrade the package for the changes.

[Error when creating graph with mplfinance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68613183/error-when-creating-graph-with-mplfinance/68614251#68614251)

Comment: Hi I tried and it does not work. I am using package yahoo_earnings_calendar not yfinance. But I think both problem result from yahoo's web scrape policy.

Comment: @ZhibaiLuo  When you say you tried, *did you include* **`pip uninstall yahoo-earnings-calendar`** and **`pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir yahoo-earnings-calendar`** ??