# error : json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, pandas

```
stock_df = pd.DataFrame()
stock = []
stock = yf.download(ticker, start= start_date, end= end_date, progress= False)
stock_df= stock_df.append(stock, sort= False)
stock_df['Symbol'] = ticker
```

```
Exception in thread Thread-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/learn-env/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/learn-env/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/learn-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/multitasking/__init__.py", line 102, in _run_via_pool
    return callee(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/learn-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yfinance/multi.py", line 166, in _download_one_threaded
    data = _download_one(ticker, start, end, auto_adjust, back_adjust,
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/learn-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yfinance/multi.py", line 178, in _download_one
    return Ticker(ticker).history(period=period, interval=interval,
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/learn-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yfinance/base.py", line 155, in history
    data = data.json()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/learn-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 898, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/learn-env/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/learn-env/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/learn-env/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: General consensus is that yfinance==0.1.62 or newer fixes the issue. Duplicates ->  [yfinance json.decoder.JSONDecodeError](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68328050/15497888), [The same code that used to work is now returning an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68331693/15497888), [When I run this simple file I get this .json error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68331957/15497888)

Comment: This means yfinance is not returning a valid JSON object.